# Microsoft Q# output to WPF or Windows Form

Tags: quantum-computing, q#

It is possible to interface a Q# class with a Windows Form or a WPF? The examples Microsoft provide in their Quantum Development Tool Kit seem only to interface with a Console.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Quantum Development Kit relies on .NET to run, so it should work with anything that uses .NET. Majority of the Q# samples use .NET Core, but [PythonInterop](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum/tree/master/Samples/PythonInterop) sample uses .NET Standard instead of .NET Core, so Quantum Development Kit can be used from Framework-only projects as well.

We haven't tried WPF or Windows Forms, though. In the libraries and samples repository, the sample [H2SimulationGUI](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum/tree/master/Samples/H2SimulationGUI) which requires visualization uses the Electron framework to do it.

Comment: If you could point to or provide some example code of how to setup a Driver.cs file to start a Windows Form and then call a QuantumSimulator that would be much appreciated as I am running into a lot of errors.

Comment: I've never worked with Windows Form, so have really no idea how to do that. But once you've added the NuGet packages as dependencies, you can create an instance of QuantumSimulator in any place in which you'd normally write C# code.